# Python argparse: single-valued argument but allow specified multiple times on command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

In python `argparse`, is it possible to declare an argument which is just single-valued, instead a list, but allows being specified multiple times, the latest one overrides the earlier ones?

The use case is, I am writing a Python program that reads command line argument from a ~/.xxxrc file, where .xxxrc file has an command line argument per line.  I want to allow user override the value in ~/.xxxrc file through command line.  My plan is to implicitly adds an `@~/.xxxrc` to the beginning of `argv` before passing it to `argparse`, so that `argparse` will reads in the file.  Now the problem turns into my question above.

Is it possible to achieve this effect?  If not, is there any alternative solution to my use case.

Comment: I would strongly recommend abandoning argparse in favor of [docopt](http://docopt.org/). Its much less verbose, usually more flexible, and it comes with the added benefit of encouraging docstrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `argparse` module does that by default. Take a look at this example, where we specify the same flag twice, and the last one wins:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='example')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add')
options = parser.parse_args(['-a', 'foo', '-a', 'bar'])
print 'add = {}'.format(options.add) # output: add = bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just create a custom action with an `nargs='*'` or `nargs='+'`.

Something like this should work:

```
class GetLastAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values[-1])


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', nargs='+', action=GetLastAction)
```